# Mvc Filter for particular url or route that doesnt have controller

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to set MVC Filter for request that fits particular url, lets say "/MyCustomAction"?

I would like serve some content (dynamic javascript) without adding the controller. The setup should be "modular" - I mean I would like to plug-in to any exisiting mvc application.

**The idea behind:**
Based on examples and other existing implementations I have wrote Json Localizer that stores locales inside .json files. Localization works fine for views and controllers. But there are also some localization requirements at client end with javascript. I would like to use same json (key-value) structure to store localized strings for javascript. But since it is required on client side i have to include provide javascript inteface to locales.

My idea is to prepare an action that will serve json file content wrapped with additional javascript object that can be accessed thru global scope. Let's say:

list.en-US.json:

```
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2"
}
```

served javascript (lets say: /localizer/en-US/list.js):

```
MyApp = MayApp || {};
MyApp.currentCulture = "@currentCulture.Name";
MyApp.Locale = {
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2"
}
```

Now in any view i would like to include:

```
<script src="/localizer/@currentCulture.Name/list.js"></script>
```

And late on inside this view:

```
<script>
 alert(MyApp.Locale.key1);
</script>
```

That's the concept. Now i'm looking for implementation for it.

It Man.

Comment: It would be more useful if you provide some examples of code how would you use your filter and what you expect from it.

Comment: Do you want to provide `list.en-US.json` for `list.js` without `Controller`? If so, there is no need to use filter, you could place `list.en-US.json` in `wwwroot` folder, and then request this file with `StaticFile Middleware` which request this file with url directly.

Comment: list.en-US.json cannot be seved as script because it is plain json it has to wrapped with some additional javascript that will define access scope. It's like injecting json into .js and that js file should be served.